# Why would a generic function require the Copy trait when the parameters are passed in as references?

Tags: function, generics, rust, addition, division

My main programming language is Java and I've just started to get into lower level languages like C/C++ and Rust. Since Java has a garbage collector, I've never really had to worry about memory management. Getting into C/C++ and Rust made me realize how little I know about pointers, referencing, etc.

If I have a simple generic function such as:

```
fn get_average <T> (x: &T, y: &T) -> T
    where T: Add<Output = T> + Div<Output = T> + From<u8>
{
    (*x + *y) / T::from(2)
}
```

The compiler will output the following:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*x` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\main.rs:12:6
   |
12 |     (*x + *y) / T::from(2)
   |     -^^------
   |     ||
   |     |move occurs because `*x` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |     `*x` moved due to usage in operator
   |
note: calling this operator moves the left-hand side

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*y` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\main.rs:12:11
   |
12 |     (*x + *y) / T::from(2)
   |           ^^ move occurs because `*y` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Why would T need the 'Copy' trait when I'm passing in x and y as references? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `Div` trait consumes both of its operands instead of borrowing: [`fn div(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Div.html). Hence, you either need to consume them as well and pass ownership to the operator, or copy and pass ownership of the copy.

Comment: Thought experiment: if `T` is not copy, then what do you expect `*x` to do when `x` is a `&T`? How would `*x` obtain a `T`?